# Validar una fechar en formato : 30/4/2013

Tags: c

Tengo una problema con este ejercicio en *C*, al momento de poner la fecha con las "/" no me imprime si el año es valido o no

**Ejercicio:** *Pedir al usuario una fecha, en este formato: 30/4/2013
Indicar si la fecha es válida o no. Chequear lo siguiente:
-que la función scanf pudo leer 3 valores
-que el mes sea válido
-que el día exista en ese mes
-que el año esté entre 1900 y 2100*

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int DIA, MES, ANIO;
    
    printf("Ingresa la fecha en formato: dd/mm/aaaa");
    printf("\nDigite el dia/mes/anio: ");
    scanf("%i %i %i",&DIA,&MES,&ANIO);
    
    if(DIA >=1)
    {
        if(DIA <=31)
        {
            printf("\nEL DIA EXISTE");
        }else
        {
            printf("\nESE DIA NO EXISTE EN EL MES");
        }
    }
    if(MES >=1)
    {
        if(MES <=12)
        {
            printf("\nEL MES EXISTE");
        }else
        {
            printf("\nEL MES NO EXISTE");   
        }
    }
    if(ANIO >= 1900)
    {
        if(ANIO <=2100)
        {
            printf("\nEL ANIO EXISTE");
        }else
        {
            printf("\nEL ANIO NO EXISTE");  
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Les adjunto un par de fotos de la ejecución del programa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lectura altamente recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El formato de entrada lo pides de esta manera dd/mm/aaaa, por lo tanto cada variable en el scanf no puede estar con separaciones sino con slash "/", de esta manera scanf("%i/%i/%i",&DIA,&MES,&ANIO); con esta modificación ya puedes dar solución.

Esta es tu línea de código en tu código. scanf("%i %i %i",&DIA,&MES,&ANIO);, esta con separaciones. toma las recomendaciones y solucionaras.

Espero te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió un montón tu ayuda

Comment: Es con todo gusto amigo. saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Al ejecutar tu código me muestra el mensaje de año... lo que si es que no es el esperado porque si colocas 31/07/1999, los valores de `DIA`, `MES`, `ANIO` son `21`, `103`, `5975664` respectivamente, esto se debe a que las variables están tomando los "/", que deberían ser ignorados.

Cuando quieres ignorar caracteres en *C* conozco dos formas de hacerlo (si alguien conoce alguna otra forma por favor comentelo^^):

**Forma 1:**
Hacer uso de `%*`, esto le dice a `scanf()` que debe ignorar el elemento posterior a este, por ejemplo `%*c`, ignorara el siguiente carácter (solo 1).

**Forma 2:**
Simplemente especificando lo que quieres que sea ignorado, este es el caso de tu problema, donde especificas que sea ignorado un `" "` entre los números, cualquier otro carácter sera tomado por las variables y dará resultados indeseables.

Por tanto tu `scanf` debería quedar así:

```
scanf("%i%*c%i%*c%i",&DIA,&MES,&ANIO);
```

Ejecutando el código pasandole 31/12/1999 tras el arreglo de scanf:

```
Ingresa la fecha en formato: dd/mm/aaaa
Digite el dia/mes/anio: 31/07/1999

EL DIA EXISTE
EL MES EXISTE
EL ANIO EXISTE
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió un montón tu ayuda